# Getting a TypeError after a fetch API call in react

Tags: reactjs, api, jsx, fetch-api

I fetched a data from an api but the when i try to access the return value from my react, it gives a typeError meaning that the data to work on as not been fetched yet.

note that as I still needed to get some datas from the data i fetched before using it in my jsx, So the data gotten from the parent Data I fetched was the one using in the jsx.

MY FETCH HOOK:

```
const options = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "027b4e223cmshf5ee3e05015b90fp1b780bjsn09ab8f5ed4c9",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "livescore6.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};

  const [value, setValue] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url, options)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setValue(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, [url]);

  return [value];
```

GETTING THE RESULT

```
const [data] = useFetch("https://livescore6.p.rapidapi.com/news/v2/list");

  async function getFeatured() {
    const featuredResult = await data.homepageArticles[0].articles;
    settheFeatured([featuredResult[0], featuredResult[1]]);
  }
  getFeatured();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer

That's because your component gets data with empty object, but your function is already called and try to get data from it. So when your data will be fetch and you set it via `useState` function then your component will be re-rendered and your data will be available.

Try to set default state of `useState` to undefined and write a condition to check exist data or not. You can also remove `await` in your `getFeatured` function